# . .bash_profile and . ./.bash_profile (./ and .)

Tags: bash

I understand `.bash_profile` is a hidden file hence the period infront.

I understand to execute a script under the current directory. You must specify `./`,  But I am not sure, why since we are already in the current directory and the script is within the current directory.

**q1)** Why must we still `./` ? Can we just put the name of the script ?

**q2)** What is the difference between `. bash_profile` and `. ./.bash_profile`?
Is `.` referring to current directory or `.` = sourcing ?

==================================

#### Add-on Questions

Below is my PATH

```
[oracle@SJOAM scripts]$ echo $PATH
.:/usr/local/java/bin:/usr/local/java/db/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/oracle/bin:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/local/bin:/u01/app/oracle/dba_scripts/bin
```

As you can see, it does not end with a : and there is no space thereafter.
I am now in the directory

```
[oracle@SJOAM bin]$ cd ~/scripts
[oracle@SJOAM scripts]$ pwd
/home/oracle/scripts
[oracle@SJOAM scripts]$ ls
rmanbkp.sh  test.sh
```

But i am still able to execute test.sh wihout specifying ./test.sh  /home/oracle/scripts is not inside my $PATH

=============================

Q1) Why am i still able to execute the script without specifying ./ ?

Q2) If my $PATH has directory that does not exists, does the search continue through the rest of the PATH ?

Q3) Does a invalid directory in the $PATH = current directory ?

Comment: You may want to look at your PATH a bit more closely. The current directory, `.`, is the very first thing in it. That may clear up some of your confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### q1

When a command is specified without a directory, then the PATH is searched for the command.  If the command is not found on the PATH, then an error message is issued.  This is for your safety and security.

If a command is specified with a path, then the shell assumes that you know what you are doing and runs that command.

Sometimes, people put the current directory in the PATH.  The PATH is a colon-separated list of directories.  If one of those directories is empty, then it is interpreted as the current directory.  For example, in this PATH, the empty space after the last colon is interpreted as being the current directory:

```
$ echo $PATH
/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/bin:
```

With such a PATH, you can execute a command in the current directory without specifying `./` in front of its name.  Be aware, though, that this may sometime lead to an unpleasant surprise.

### q2

Yes, a leading dot-space means *source* the script.  Sourcing a script means that it is run in the current shell, not in a subshell.  A sourced script can change the current environment.  A script in a subshell cannot.  The following two commands are equivalent:

```
source ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
```

In summary, (1) a leading dot-space on the command line means 'source the script' and (2) a leading dot on a file name means the file is hidden.  These two uses of dot are separate and independent.

#### Q1

The first directory in your PATH is `.` which is the current directory.  That is why you are able to execute scripts in the current directory without specifying their directory.

Because the current directory is specified first, that PATH is especially dangerous: it means that any script in the current directory will take precedence over all the standard executables in `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, etc.  This may cause failure of any program that expects to be able to run the usual executables.

#### Q2

Let's do a test by adding a non-existent directory, call it `nonsense`, to the PATH:

```
$ type date
date is hashed (/bin/date)
$ export PATH=/usr/bin/:nonsense:/bin
$ hash -r  # delete the cache
$ date
Thu Jul  9 11:13:18 PDT 2015
```

Invalid paths are ignored and the search continues on with the next element in the PATH list.

#### Q3

No, bad directories on the PATH are not interpreted as the current directory.  For example:

```
$ export PATH=/usr/bin/:nonsense
$ date
bash: date: command not found
$ cd /bin
$ date
bash: date: command not found
$ ./date
Thu Jul  9 11:17:34 PDT 2015
```

Comment: edited my question, please have a look

Comment: @Noob I updated the answer for your revised questions.

Comment: thanks - i didn't see the  . Can you also let me know if the OS encounter a invalid or empty directory in the middle of the path, does it carry on search the remaining path ?

Comment: @Noob I added information on invalid directories.  An empty directory, whether at the beginning (leading colon `:`), the end (trailing colon `:`), or the middle (two adjacent colons `::`), is  interpreted as the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

The filename is `.bash_profile` with a leading dot.

The command to source a file into the current shell is `.` (dot)

So, you want `. .bash_profile` -- (command="." ; argument=".bash_profile"`)

Another way of saying that which may be more obvious:

```
filename=".bash_profile"
. "$filename"
```